# Shower leaking at joint

Tags: shower

[image]
New shower in new house has been causing serious problems.  Initially leaking out both sides and down through to downstairs along copper pipes into a cupboard containing gas heating equipment.  Got that stopped after lots of sealing.  Then water started to leak out both sides of shower at the joints where the wall frame and the base of the shower frame meet.  Despite numerous sealing and removing door a new door has been fitted and again the same leak is appearing.  Any ideas???? Driving me crazy and contractor doesn’t seem to know!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Why isn't it the contractor's job to figure it out?

Comment: The contractor has the fitters in constantly trying to figure it out but quite clearly they haven’t a clue.  It’s a guessing game.

Comment: This has been on-going now for 8 months trying different things.  They have tried everything bar stripping it all back taking tiles off.  They thought main issue was the floor dropping.